# why isn't this code working in internet explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, toggle

All of browser works except IE.
Why isn't working in IE?? Please help!

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j2wintery/ZzKWw)

```
<script language = "javascript"> 
function ImageList(photo) {
    var ImageList = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for (var x = 0; x < ImageList.length; x++) {
        name = ImageList[x].getAttribute("class");
        if (name == 'ImageList-1') {
            if (ImageList[x].id == photo) {
                if (ImageList[x].style.display == 'block') {
                    ImageList[x].style.display = 'none';
                } else {
                    ImageList[x].style.display = 'block';
                }
            } else {
                ImageList[x].style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    }
}

function SpaceList(list) {
    var SpaceList = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for (var x = 0; x < SpaceList.length; x++) {
        name = SpaceList[x].getAttribute("class");
        if (name == 'SpaceList-1') {
            if (SpaceList[x].id == list) {
                if (SpaceList[x].style.display == 'block') {
                    SpaceList[x].style.display = 'none';
                } else {
                    SpaceList[x].style.display = 'block';
                }
            } else {
                SpaceList[x].style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    }
} 
</script>
```

Comment: What is happening? Are you seeing any errors? Open Developer Tools (F12) to view the error console.

Comment: the function isn't work locally in IE (not in server or anything) I am testing on my computer but nothing happen in IE. Other browsers shows fine tho. why is that?

Answer (score 2):

Your function name `ImageList` and variable `ImageList` are conflicting. Use different names. 
The same with `SpaceList`

Also, On a side note - `<script language="javascript>` has been deprecated, and needs to be replaced by `<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: do you meant variable name? or function name? Could you please give an example for me? Thanks

Comment: change the function name and try. that will be easier, just make sure the local variable, and function name are not the same..

Comment: I changed function names...now it's not working at all... what should i do.......T.T

Comment: did you change the function name from where it is being called ?

Comment: I changed, function ImageListx(photo) {  this section. is there other name do i need to change too? I really thanks for your help tho.

Comment: Ok.. did you change this from the place it is being called from ?

Comment: what example do i make? all i am saying is, at some place in your code - you would be caling `ImageList()` right? Just replace that with `ImageListx`

Comment: I did changed both function name and calling to ImageListx but still nothing happen in IE..... did I miss anything?

Comment: can you create a fiddle of you use case? jsfiddle.net

Comment: Code looks fine - in the fiddle, it is cribbing about extra </div> can you fix them ?